# Very different query plans with and without LIMIT in PostgreSQL.

Tags: postgresql, optimization, performance, hints, postgresql-performance

I have the following query which I am using to create vector tiles for a web map. I'm pulling together just the geometries within the selected tile using a CTE, then joining it to get additional attribute information.

```
WITH lots AS (
  SELECT pams_pin, shape
    FROM parcels
   WHERE ST_Transform(shape,3857) && TileBBox($z, $x, $y)
)
SELECT p.pams_pin, v.property_location, v.property_class
     , v.owner_name, v.owner_address, v.owner_city, v.owner_zip
     , ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(p.shape,4326), 7) as shape
  FROM lots p
  LEFT JOIN mv_modiv_sr1a v ON p.pams_pin = v.pams_pin
;
```

This is incredibly slow, taking several seconds to return a result. However, if I take this same query and add `LIMIT 500` to the end, it returns results almost immediately.

Here's the output from `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` [with the limit](http://explain.depesz.com/s/LXVL) and [without the limit](http://explain.depesz.com/s/z1cy).

Why does the query planner take such a different path when a `LIMIT` clause is added? Is there any way to force this more efficient plan without using `LIMIT`? While in this case, `LIMIT 500` should not result in any missing records, I'd like a better understanding of why this is occuring and if there's a way to provide a hint to the planner to use the smaller set within the CTE instead of driving the results from the ~3 million record table and then throwing a massive amount of data away.